# How to modify zoom level of gnome-terminal programatically?

Tags: gnome-terminal

One can modify the zoom level in the gnome-terminal by pressing C-+/-. I would like to modify the zoom level automatically in response to window size change (number of columns). Alternatively, are there terminals which support that? I am using a tiling window manager and would like to have the font adjust to the size of the window so that there is roughly constant number of characters in a line.